# Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.2.71'] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a fresh install of IntelliJ, I created a new kotlin gradle project using the following settings:

[image: Project settings]

This produces the following build.gradle.kts, (the exact same file works on my Windows machine):

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.2.71"
}

group = "com.test"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Which produces this error, when trying to do a gradle refresh:

> Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.2.71'] was not
>   found in any of the following sources:
>
> - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
> - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.2.71')
>     Searched in the following repositories:
>     Gradle Central Plugin Repository

Comment: Please check that "Offline" option is not enabled in "Settings | Build... | Build Tools | Gradle"

Comment: @y.bedrov, it is not enabled.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Considering just using a `build.gradle` instead

Comment: I have the same issue with `build.gradle`, so I don't think it's related to the Kotlin DSL build script (on macos).

Comment: I have the same problem with both using `build.gradle` or Kotlin DSL as well. Different PC, same internet connection it works. Tried to invalidate IntelliJ cache to no avail.

Comment: In my case I didn't specify a version for kotlin("jvm"), maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 22):

Check your Internet connection and make sure your Internet is not restricted.

I solved this problem by turning on proxy for all tunnels (not just HTTP) with a VPN app.

Comment: VPN was solved my problem

Comment: Restarting my router worked!

Answer (score 8):

Check your gradle and kotlin (or Java) versions.

I got the same error and my issue is solved by specifying the kotlin version in build.gradle:

Before:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
}
```

After:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version "1.4.10"
}
```

Comment: `org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'] was not found in any of the following sources`

Answer (score 7):

check if you are not in **gradle offline mode**

[image]

Comment: this one is my case! !!!

Comment: Restarting my router worked!

Answer (score 6):

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
//    kotlin("jvm") version "1.2.71"
}

group = "com.test"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
}

//tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
//    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
//}
```

1. gradle sync by commenting the above lines. The gradle will be set up.
2. once the gradle is downloaded, uncomment those line and sync again.
3. if the dependencies are not downloaded properly, run 'gradle build' in the terminal and click on gradle sync.

This solved the issue for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want to improve your answer please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55929627/edit) button instead of adding a comment. [Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) should be used for asking for more information or for suggesting improvements.

Answer (score 5):

**(1)** in my case (OpenJDK 11 on Ubuntu 18.04) the problem was Gradle not being able to download the POM file from gradle plugin-server. you can test it by entering this line into `jshell`:

```java
new java.net.URL("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/jvm/org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin/1.3.11/org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin-1.3.11.pom").openStream()
```

(you can find your url by running gradle with `--debug` option)

So if you received an exception like this: **InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty** then the trouble is **CA-certs cache**. which could be easily fixed by writing these lines into bash [Ref](https://gist.github.com/mikaelhg/527204e746984cf9a33f7910bb8b4cb6):

```sh
sudo su
/usr/bin/printf '\xfe\xed\xfe\xed\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe2\x68\x6e\x45\xfb\x43\xdf\xa4\xd9\x92\xdd\x41\xce\xb6\xb2\x1c\x63\x30\xd7\x92' > /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
/var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure
```

By the way do not forget to restart gradle daemon before trying again. (`gradle --stop`)

**(2)** another reason could be your internet not having access to `bintray.com` (the internet of Iran or China) which you can test by putting this line on `jshell` :

```java
new java.net.URL("https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin-api/1.3.11/kotlin-gradle-plugin-api-1.3.11.pom").openStream()
```

If you received a **connection timeout**, it confirms this theory. In this case you need to buy and have proxy/vpn connected in order to be able to download these dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, no verbosity level for gradle would point out that the certificate wasnt beign recognized, and as I could get the pom from the browser i had no clue why it wasnt working. Testing it from jshell like you suggested made it pretty clear to me. What i just can't understand is why my JVM out of nowhere decided it doesnt trust the main gradle plugin repository... Java is painfull

Answer (score 5):

I updated my Kotlin version to `1.7.20` and fixed this problem.

`id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. Thanks! I tried all the solutions above and they didn't work in my case

Answer (score 4):

If you are using java like me .I got the issue fixed by adding the following:

**Root gradle**

```
dependencies {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.10'

        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        ......
    }
```

**App gradle file**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

    dependencies {
        implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1"
        kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.38.1"
        ......

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was because **Charles Proxy**. After closing Charles I could start working again

Comment: it sloved my problem

Answer (score 3):

In my case (Ubuntu 20.04), problem was with gradle 7.2, installed from snap.

I have removed gradle 7.2, installed from snap and install gradle 7.2 from [sdkman](https://sdkman.io). Works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so the answer was very simple all along. For some reason I activated gradle's "Offline work" toggle and that was the cause of the problem.

To disable it simply go to `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle` and deselect the "Offline work" checkbox.

Comment: In IDEA 2022.3, there is no checkbox, so I thought this was irrelevant. Then I saw that `.idea > gradle.xml` had the following line: `<option name="offlineMode" value="true" />`, which should be removed. So annoying.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I changes the Gradle JVM  in `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect from your VPN (or make sure you have an open internet connection), then restart Android Studio.

If you don't restart it sometimes it continues with invalid proxy properties.

Answer (score 1):

[https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/38853][1]

[React Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) says:
If you already have a JDK on your system, we recommend JDK17. You may encounter problems using higher JDK versions.

If you're using the latest version of Java Development Kit, you'll need to change the Gradle version of your project so it can recognize the JDK. You can do that by going to`{project root folder}\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` and changing the distributionUrl value to upgrade the Gradle version. You can check out [here the latest releases of Gradle](https://gradle.org/releases/).

Things that worked for me was to run the following command :
`choco install -y microsoft-openjdk17`
to install the correct version of JDK and install the required Android SDK's and ensure that they are corrctly present in the environment Variables.

Copy and paste `Get-ChildItem -Path Env:\` into powershell to verify that JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME path is present in environment variables

Comment: It is Basically about the incorrect JDK version for React Native, if this solution doesn't works trying checkin all the versions of node, Jdk, android Sdk, kotlin and gradle

Answer (score 0):

I recently had similar issue with an empty project autogenerated by `Intellij Idea`.

Solved this problem by combining `Java` and `Gradle` versions.

Initially I had `Oracle Java 8` with `Gradle 6.8.3`.

After several attempts I found a working combination - `AdoptOpenJDK 11` and `Gradle 5.6.4`

Answer (score 0):

This for Ktor devs. If you are working on a ktor application with the web project generator there is a chance the generator sets invalid *jvm plugin version*. So make sure you are setting correct version for jvm plugin. You can find the latest [jvm plugin version here](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm). Here is the sample build.gradle.kts file.

```
//Plugin section
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.0"
    id("io.ktor.plugin") version "2.2.2"
}

//Dependancy section
dependencies {
   ...

   testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-tests-jvm:1.8.0")
   testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.8.0")

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting `Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jvm:1.8.20.`

This is because the generated `build.gradle` uses the kotlin_version to get the jvm and as of right now there is no 1.8.20 version. there are only RC versions of the JVM for that version.
[image]

I changed the version to 1.2.10 and it built just fine. So if you come across this, check [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-scripting-jvm) to see if `plugins.kotlin("jvm") version` is using a version that doesn't yet exist.

Answer (score 0):

`gradle --stop` after `npx react-native run-android` wordked for me

Answer (score 0):

in my case BurpSuite was on and as soon as I closed it everything was working.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue where I received the error: "Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.8.21'] was not found in any of the following sources". This happened after migrating my Kotlin project to use an organization-specific artifact repository. The problem was resolved by correctly configuring the pluginManagement section in the settings.gradle.kts file.

When switching to a different artifact repository, it's crucial to specify the new repository in the pluginManagement block so Gradle knows where to find the required plugins. Here’s how I updated my **settings.gradle.kts**:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url = uri("<repository url>") // Replace with your actual repository URL
            credentials {
                username = "<user>" // Replace with your repository username
                password = "<pass>" // Replace with your repository password
            }
        }
        // You can also include the Gradle Plugin Portal if needed
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

gradle.properties content was my issue... I tried to create new project in IntelliJ Idea after several days of searching and testing a lot of solutions. And I could see that my gradle.properties contains several rows more than the new one:

```html
kotlin.code.style=official // this line only remains

systemProp.http.proxyHost=localhost
systemProp.http.proxyPort=9001

systemProp.https.proxyHost=localhost
systemProp.https.proxyPort=9001
```

so I deleted rows with systemProp... and it works now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your kotlin plugin version to the latest version in the build.gradle project file like this

before - id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false

after - id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.22' apply false

this worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).