# react-native run-android gives err FAILURE:Build failed Where: Build file 'C:\...\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\build.gradle.kts' line: 11

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, gradle, react-native-cli

i am new to react-native cli
any time i run npm run android in my react-native project after opening the emulator and js server

while it throws an error saying

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\native1\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\build.gradle.kts' line: 11
```

in full

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\native1\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\build.gradle.kts' line: 11

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.6.10'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (None of the included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.6.10')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    MavenRepo
    Google
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11m 1s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\native1\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\build.gradle.kts' line: 11

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.6.10'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (None of the included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.6.10')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    MavenRepo
    Google
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11m 1s

    at makeError (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\native1\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\HP\Desktop\native1\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\native1\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\native1\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! native1@0.0.1 android: `react-native run-android`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the native1@0.0.1 android script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-01T14_25_45_278Z-debug.log
```

any sugestion will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This part is the interesting:

```
Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.6.10'] was not found in any of the following sources:
```

The same [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52562735/plugin-id-org-jetbrains-kotlin-jvm-version-1-2-71-was-not-found-in-any).

Answer (score 0):

In your project gradle file,

change
`org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm`
to
`org.jetbrains.kotlin.android`

Maybe this will help.
Basically, gradle could not find the kotlin plugin dependency in any of the sources.

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me trying to get Android/Google TV development with React Native running. Make sure you add this "Android TV ARM 64 v8a System Image (if you chose a Android TV as emulator). That seemed to do the trick for me.

[image: Add Android TV ARM]